# why factoryGirl don't rollback after build and save in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I don't understand why my record in 2 spec is not rollback:
I have 2 tables, prefecture has_many hospitals

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe Hospital, type: :model, focus: true do

context "created along with new hospital created" do

    it "should create new hospital" do
        @prefecture = FactoryGirl.create(:prefecture)
        hospital = FactoryGirl.build(:hospital, id: 10, prefecture: @prefecture)
        expect { hospital.save }.to change { Hospital.count }.by 1
    end

    it "should save" do
        @prefecture = FactoryGirl.create(:prefecture)
        hospital = FactoryGirl.build(:hospital, id: 10, prefecture: @prefecture)
        hospital.save
    end
end

end
```

If I run it will show error "id=10 is existed in db"
Can anyone explain where I am mistake?
Thank you.

Comment: In your `spec_helper.rb`, do you have `config.use_transactional_fixtures = true`?

Comment: @Hoa No, I tried to use that command but it show me error. If I remove "id: 10" in hospital build then it passed but I don't know why.

Comment: Without that configuration, the same data is re-used in all the tests. That's why you can't save another hospital with id = 10 in the 2nd test because you already create one from the 1st test. If you remove id = 10, of course it works because now you have 2 hospitals with different IDs (no ID conflict). What error is it when you add the configuration?

Comment: Thank you. that line added in rails_helper instead of spec_helper :)

Comment: Right, I didn't notice that you require `rails_helper` instead of `spec_helper` in your specs.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the responsibility of FactoryGirl. You have 2 options:

- Use transactions in tests: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/transactions
- Use a gem which cleans DB after after test such as: https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner

Usually your models test will use transctions and database cleaner is used for integration/acceptance tests which cannot operate within transaction because a separate process (browser) needs to read the data created in tests.

Comment: I want to know why my test cases is not passed. As I know, each test spec will rollback but in my case it is not rollback. If I remove "id: 10" in hospital build then it pass.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the rspec will not reset your database for each test. You need to configure it. Is because that your second test is falling, already exists a **Hospital** with **id = 10**.

When you remove the parameter **id** for the second test and runs with success, **FactoryGirl** will generate automatically a **new** **id**.

The method **build** from FactoryGirl will **not fill** the attribute **id**, just the rest of the attributes. Is because that when you call **save** after **build** method, the FactoryGirll generate a **new** **id** and your tests pass successfully.

Answer (score 0):

after :build do |offer|
offer.save
end